# Visualforce: Convert String into dropdown values

Tags: visualforce, multi-select, selectlist, selectoption

Trying to render the list on visualforce page and convert multiselect picklist into dropdown instead of getting selectoptions from controller.

```
 Class returntoVF {
        String name;
        object someOtherObject;
    }
```

`someotherobject` has a multiselect picklist Fieldname (abc) and lets say values selected in this multiselect picklist are `a;b;c;`

`List<returntoVF>` is sent to VF page and apex:repeat is used as follows:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!returntoVF_List}" var="s">
    <apex:selectList size="1">
        <apex:selectoptions value="s.someOtherObject.abc.split(';')" />  <!--Looking to render this list as dropdown-->
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to a `List<SelectOption>`:

```
public List<SelectOption> options { get; set; }
public ReturnToVf()
{
    // one place to put this code would be in your constructor
    options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (String option : abc.split(';'))
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(option, option));
    }
}
```

Then you would just bind the value to this list:

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!options}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian for this but I am trying to think of ways to avoid apex here .

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be done with just markup.

Comment: I was using APEX earlier but thinking of ways if it can be achieved directly in VF. I expeimented with split and some string functions but was not able to achieve so posted question here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm telling you it can't be done. Maybe someone will prove me wrong...

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Will see if someone has done this.. Thanks...

Comment: @sf_user Visualforce doesn't have a way to express things like splitting strings. If `returnToVF` were a List of String, you could probably get away with it, but you definitely *must* split in Apex Code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using only visualforce but was not able to achieve however, here is something I figured out works for me and is completely javascript and html:

```
<select name="options" id="options">
    <script>
        var select = document.getElementById( 'options' );
        var option;
        var input = '{!s.someOtherObject.abc}'; 
        input.split(';').forEach(function(item) {
            option = document.createElement( 'option' );
            option.value = option.textContent = item;
            select.appendChild(option);
        });
    </script>
</select>
```

Comment: But then you have to arrange for a hidden variable elsewhere, because the select list won't be tied to any real VF binding.

Comment: yeah.. thats the downside i guess..

Comment: Also you need to escape any string you use in Javascript.